# C# - Crop Transparent/White space

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, gdi+, crop

I'm trying to remove all white or transparent pixels from an image, leaving the actual image (cropped). I've tried a few solutions, but none seem to work. Any suggestions or am I going to spend the night writing image cropping code?

Comment: So there ARE other people who dream of continously writing the same line of code over and over again? I thought I was the only one :-)

Comment: it would help the community if you details at least one of your approaches and explained how it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public Bitmap CropBitmap(Bitmap original)
{
    // determine new left
    int newLeft = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
        {
            Color color = original.GetPixel(x, y);
            if ((color.R != 255) || (color.G != 255) || (color.B != 255) || 
                (color.A != 0))
            {
                // this pixel is either not white or not fully transparent
                newLeft = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (newLeft != -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        // repeat logic for new right, top and bottom

    }

    Bitmap ret = new Bitmap(newRight - newLeft, newTop - newBottom);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ret)
    {
        // copy from the original onto the new, using the new coordinates as
        // source coordinates for the original
        g.DrawImage(...);
    }

    return ret
}
```

Note that this function will be slow as dirt.  `GetPixel()` is unbelievably slow, and accessing the `Width` and `Height` properties of a `Bitmap` inside a loop is also slow.  `LockBits` would be the proper way to do this - there are tons of examples here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, that got me half way there. The only problem is, I also want to resize the image if it's bigger than a specified size. There's more code than will fit in the comments box, but the original image only takes up about half the final image.  The code is at http://pastebin.com/He3S8aCH

Comment: I transposed two variables :P. Problem fixed, expect a blog post soon (will link to it here).

Comment: I think I screwed up, too. The bits that say `color.R != 0` etc. should actually say `color.R != 255`, since a white pixel will have R, G and B values of 255 for each (an RGB of 0,0,0 is black). If the original version worked for you, then it probably only cropped the transparent (and the black) pixels.

Comment: Also, the code should probably first check the A value to see if the pixel is transparent, and then only check the RGB values if the pixel *isn't* transparent. Otherwise, the check will stop on any fully transparent (A = 0) non-white pixel (although I doubt this is very common in Bitmaps).

Answer (score 11):

So, what you want to do is find the top, left most non white/transparent pixel and the bottom, right most non white/transparent pixel. These two coordinates will give you a rectangle that you can then extract.

```
  // Load the bitmap
  Bitmap originalBitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("d:\\temp\\test.bmp") as Bitmap;

  // Find the min/max non-white/transparent pixels
  Point min = new Point(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
  Point max = new Point(int.MinValue, int.MinValue);

  for (int x = 0; x < originalBitmap.Width; ++x)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < originalBitmap.Height; ++y)
    {
      Color pixelColor = originalBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
      if (!(pixelColor.R == 255 && pixelColor.G == 255 && pixelColor.B == 255)
        || pixelColor.A < 255)
      {
        if (x < min.X) min.X = x;
        if (y < min.Y) min.Y = y;

        if (x > max.X) max.X = x;
        if (y > max.Y) max.Y = y;
      }
    }
  }

  // Create a new bitmap from the crop rectangle
  Rectangle cropRectangle = new Rectangle(min.X, min.Y, max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y);
  Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(cropRectangle.Width, cropRectangle.Height);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
  {
    g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, 0, 0, cropRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  }
```

Comment: Great solution! I removed `|| pixelColor.A < 255` to make it work.

Comment: Similar comment - works almost perfectly, in my case I wanted to just crop all and only the *transparent* section. I just changed the whole conditional to just " if (pixelColor.A > 0)". Everything else worked the way I wanted at that point.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF we have a WriteableBitmap class. Is this what are you looking for ? If it is the case please have a look at [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalasyn/archive/2008/04/17/using-writeablebitmap-to-display-a-procedural-texture.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgalasyn/using-writeablebitmap-to-display-a-procedural-texture)

Answer (score 2):

Per-pixel check should do the trick. Scan each line to find empty line from the top & bottom, scan each row to find left & right constraints (this can be done in one pass with either rows or columns). When the constraint is found - copy the part of the image to another buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to batch trim a few thousand .jpg files in about 10 minutes, but I didn't do it in code. I used the Convert feature of Snag-It Editor. I don't know if this is an option for you, if you need to do this trimming once or your need is ongoing, but for the price of the software, which isn't a whole lot, I considered this a decent workaround. 
(I do not work for or represent Techsmith.)

Joey

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, if you are in WPF and you have excess space around your image, check the properties of the image and make sure your ***Stretch*** property is set to fill. This eliminated the space around the image.

[Screen shot of the property in WPF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sK9g.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).